# How to add a 5 sec Rewind and Fast Forward buttons to HTML5 audio player?

Tags: html, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audio-player

On a WordPress website I want to add Rewind and Forward buttons to Audio Player to let forward and backward by 5 or 10 seconds. I've searched a lot and not found any information about it. Is it possible to do it?

I'd appreciate any clue or information.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Questions on StackOverflow require showing what you've done to solve the problem yourself. Reviewing the HTMLMediaElement interface documentation would be a good place to start.

Comment: Of course I've tried and searched a lot! Offering to close the question was not a good idea. Please remove it. I've struggled a lot and don't know what can I do.

Comment: Searching "html audio change time" yields many helpful results.

Comment: The question lacks clarity. What is the audio player? Is it a Javascript solution or the native browser player? The page exists already, so please share your code. See also [How to produce a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If it’s the native player, you might be able to extend it by [Using Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) like `class 5sAudioPlayer extends HTMLAudioElement {`. But I’m not enough into custom elements to provide detailed instructions. Otherwise, adding additional buttons outside the player UI is easy. So what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible, you just have to make sure you are using the JavaScript Audio object that gives you access to the current time property that you can change to achieve this.

To initialize an audio track using this object

```
let myAudio = new Audio("audio source path");
```

To play the audio

```
myAudio.play()
```

To rewind by 5s

```
myAudio.currentTime -= 5
```

To fast forward by 5s

```
myAudio.currentTime += 5
```

Comment: Wow! That's great! I've never worked with JavaScript Audio object but I'll try to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: This is not adding buttons to an existing player, this is creating an entirely new, custom, player.

Comment: @Andy, then what's the solution? ty!

Comment: @Kardo First, it would be great if you could clarify your question. Is adding buttons to an existing player what you want? Are buttons next to it an option? Which player is being used?

Answer (score 0):

If the standard HTML player is used for the audio, it is very simple to add additional buttons that control the video.

The `<audio>` and the `<video>` element expose their [HTMLMediaElement API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) in JavaScript, which allows seeking to a certain time inside the video.

The following example is demonstrating these two buttons with 3s and a video, to make it more comprehensible with or without sound.

It is using the `fastSeek()` method, which might add a visual or audio seeking effect. If you want to be more precise in seeking, you should directly set `v.currentTime += SKIP_s`.

```js
const SKIP_s = 3;
const v = document.querySelector('video');
const fw = document.getElementById('forward');
const rw = document.getElementById('rewind');

// actually forward or rewind
fw.addEventListener('click', () => v.fastSeek(v.currentTime + SKIP_s));
rw.addEventListener('click', () => v.fastSeek(v.currentTime - SKIP_s));

// only enable buttons when the video is ready
v.addEventListener('canplay', () => fw.disabled = false, rw.disabled = false);
```

```css
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
<video controls>
<source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/8/87/Schlossbergbahn.webm/Schlossbergbahn.webm.1080p.vp9.webm" type="video/webm">

<p>Your browser does not seem to support WebM videos</p>
</video>

<button id="rewind" disabled>Rewind 3&nbsp;s</button>
<button id="forward" disabled>Forward 3&nbsp;s</button>

<figcaption>
A coach of the <span lang="de">Schlossbergbahn</span> in Graz, Austria, is mounting in its track up the mountain, passing the siding.
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Of course, you could add logic to disable the buttons if they cannot seek + or - the intended step, but `fastSeek()` already takes care of limiting the time to the video’s duration. So a click might not actually forward or rewind 5 s, but only 2, which should be acceptable.

### Customize the UI

This way you can set the buttons outside the native player’s user interface. If you wanted to present all control buttons in a coherent style, you could omit [the `controls` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-controls) and implement your own toolbar.

### Demo Video Licence

This video file is licenced under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Austria license. [Video Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Schlossbergbahn.webm)